# Improper setup of window displayed through menu item?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am working on my first native mac app after playing with iOS for a while.

I am attempting to launch a window from a menu item, but I suspect I am doing it wrong. Any `IBAction` I connect to buttons on this new window returns an error.

Here is what I am doing. From a menu item I launch this:

```
-(IBAction)displaySAInput:(id)sender{

NSLog(@"Input selected.");
inputSAViewController = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"InputViewController"];
[inputSAViewController showWindow:self];
```

This launches the `InputViewController` nib that is owned by the `InputViewController` class. I set the `InputViewController` class to inherit from `NSWindowController`.

On `InputViewController.m` I have tested `IBAction`s such as:

```
-(IBAction)testButton:(id)sender{

NSLog(@"Data recalled?");

}
```

I connect this `IBAction` to a button through the Interface Builder. All looks okay.

When I build and open the `InputViewController` window I receive this error in the console before clicking anything:

```
Could not connect the action testButton: to target of class NSWindowController
```

I have searched extensively but my ignorance prevents me from connecting the dots. This thread [based on a similar error with NSApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741564/could-not-connect-the-action-to-target-of-class-nsapplication) looks promising, but I don't quite understand what I'd need to make the connections happen related to the `NSWindowController` error.

This should be simple. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just load the NSWindow before hand and make it invisible and when the IBAction is called, just do the following:

```
[myWindow setIsVisible:YES];
[myWindow setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel];
```

Yay!

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, are you saying I should let it be under the file owner of the menu itself instead of launching it from a new class? Then just toggle its visibility?

Comment: Yes, at least that is what I have done and it works perfectly.

Comment: I ended up going this route. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
-(IBAction)displaySAInput:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Input selected.");
    inputSAViewController = [[NSWindowController alloc]
                  initWithWindowNibName:@"InputViewController"];
    [inputSAViewController showWindow:self];
}
```

Notice you are alloc/initing a generic instance of `NSWindowController`, not your custom subclass where you've implemented the `testButton:` method. I assume you'd likely want that changed to:

```
-(IBAction)displaySAInput:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Input selected.");
    inputSAViewController = [[InputViewController alloc]
                  initWithWindowNibName:@"InputViewController"];
    [inputSAViewController showWindow:self];
}
```

Comment: This sounds promising... On first attempt there was a linker error. Working to resolve.

Comment: This is the error I'm still receiving... Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_InputViewController", referenced from: objc-class-ref in ReportController.old: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Resolved linker issue (ReportController.m wasn't listed in target compile list) but still receiving error after updating to your recommendation: Could not connect the action testButton: to target of class InputViewController